# Spring Boot with HTML mapping specific fields

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have a many controllers in Spring Boot that read my documents from collection. One of them is like this:

```
 @GetMapping("/getRandomSummerCamps")
 public List<AdventureHolidays> getRandomSummerCamps() {
    return adventureHolidaysService.getRandomSummerCamps();
}
```

So its casual controller with service and repository. What is my goal for which I cant find a proper way doing it. For example, that controller is returning me API like this:

```
[{"title":"Raquette Lake Camp","description":"Founded in 1916, Raquette Lake Camp enjoys a reputation as the Harvard of summer camps, with extensive programs, state of the art lodgings, required uniforms, on-site chefs, and a difficult, exclusive application process. Those who are not grandfathered in as siblings of previous members must undergo an interview process for approximately 10 to 12 extra spots per year. Divided into both a boys camp and a girls camp separated by a lake, activities are wide and varied: gymnastics, ice hockey, horseback riding, canoeing, sailing, lacrosse, baseball, and tennis are but a few of the sports offered, while the theater and arts program are also well-regarded. At the end of summer, campers participate in a weeklong Color War, divided into two groups of green and white for boys, and blue and white for girls. While the sexes are segregated and each camp is run separately, the brother and sister camps lunch together weekly.","typeOfAdventureHolidays":"summerCamps"}]
```

From that JSON I want to consume `title` and `description`. How I can achieve that so when I call that controller it return me HTML page with just `title` and `descritpion`?

This is also model for that controller.

```
@Document("adventureholidays")
public class AdventureHolidays {

@Id
private String id;
private String title;
private String description;
private String typeOfAdventureHolidays;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getTypeOfAdventureHolidays() {
    return typeOfAdventureHolidays;
}
```

Thank you all in advance, and sorry for bad English, not native.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving typeOfAdventureHolidays `@JsonIgnore` annotation then call the controller.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).